# I can't do an Array.from on my Eventlistener change

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to do an event on my input range that is named `$aantalGrammys`. In the function, I call in the eventListener, I want to make an array of the called up array of JSON objects.

```
const $aantalGrammys = document.querySelector(`.aantalGrammys`);
    $aantalGrammys.addEventListener(`change`, handleChangeAmount);
}

const handleChangeAmount = e => {
    const $aantalGrammys = document.querySelector(`.aantalGrammys`);
    if (e.target) {
        console.log(e.currentTarget.value);
    }
}
```

I changed some things in my code by some comments but I don't really know how to use the parsed data I did previously to do read a specific array of my parsed JSON here is the changed code and some extra lines I didn't show before

```
 const createUserLine = grammy => {
     const $aantalGrammys = document.querySelector(`.aantalGrammys`);
     $aantalGrammys.addEventListener(`change`, handleChangeAmount);
 }



 const handleChangeAmount = e => {
     const $aantalGrammys = document.querySelector(`.aantalGrammys`);
         if(e.target){
             console.log(e.currentTarget.value);
         }
     }
 }

 const parseJson = () => {
     const url = `./assets/data/grammys.json`;

     fetch(url)
         .then(r => r.json())
         .then(parse);

     fetch(url)
         .then(r => r.json())
         .then(handleChangeAmount);
     }

const init = () => {
    const $form = document.querySelector(`form`);
    $form.noValidate = true;
    $form.addEventListener(`submit`, handleSubmitForm);

    parseJson();
};

init();
```

Comment: Any error in console ? Also did you debug it to see if array is properly formed ?

Comment: The parameter `grammys` in your `handleChangeAmount()` handler does hold an [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener/handleEvent) object (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_event_listener_callback)). Probably not what you are expecting. Thus the function does not behave like you think.

Comment: Good point @Kristianmitk - it will be e (event object that has many properties) and e.target is the actual DOM element

Comment: I made some changes in the code above, If anyone could help me, Your welcome! I appreciate the help I already got.